# Flutter Commands Don't Work with Intelj Idea

Tags: flutter, dart, command-line, command

Hello I am using Intelj IDEA dart editor to create Flutter projects, everything works great except I can't run the Flutter commands from inside my project directory. When I press play the editor runs 'flutter run' and it works properly, but when I try to run 'flutter run' from the terminal it says that there is no flutter command found. I've already tried configuring my PATH according to the flutter docs but still no luck. How do I configure the flutter commands to run properly, I am using MacOS.

Comment: What the file you config your PATH, can you show? If you only export, you will need to export every time you open your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

lets configure flutter with android studio

File > Settings > Languages and frameworks > Select flutter from the list > set up the path of your flutter

Answer (score 0):

cd into the flutter directory that you downloaded and unzipped from the Flutter docs and run

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```